# Can a @ManyToOne JPA relation be null?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, many-to-one

I have a table that has foreign key of another table (many to one relationship) but i want it to be nullable.

Something like this:

```
public class SubType() {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    private String id;

}

public class TopUp {

    @Column(nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private SubType subType;

}
```

But `@Column(nullable = true)` throws the `NullPointerException` and  says subtype can not be null.
Is there any way to get the ManyToOne accept null?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `@ManyToOne` associations are optional by default, so you don't need to set anything if you want them to be nullable.

However, because you set the `optional=false` attribute, you made it mandatory.

So instead of:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Set it like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

The [`optional`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/manytoone#optional()) is `true` by default.

On the other hand, the `@Column(nullable=true)` is to instruct the DDL generation tool to include a `NULL` SQL column type constraint.

Comment: That's a terrific solution, hence the number of upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "subType_id", nullable = true)
```

Comment: [`nullable` is true by default.](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#nullable--)

Answer (score 0):

Only this helped me:

```
public class TopUp {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(columnDefinition="integer", name="subtype_id")
    private SubType subType;
}
```

columnDefinition is a solution!