# Hibernate nullable=true not working in @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

This is my scenario,
I have Cars, which belong either to a Dealer or a User (not both at the same time).

So my Car entity has a @ManyToOne relation with Dealer and User, but one of them needs to be null, so I added nullable=true in both, to support that.

This is my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
@XmlRootElement
public class Car  implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_sequence", sequenceName = "car_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_sequence")
    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dealer", nullable = true)
    private Dealer dealer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", nullable = true)
    private User user;
```

But then when I try to insert a car without a Dealer I get this:

ERROR: null value in column "dealer" violates not-null constraint.

I understand that is because of a foreign key restriction generated by Hibernate in the database. But then:
 -What is the reason of having "nullable = true"?
 -How can I solve this problem where I need to have a @ManyToOne relationship and it can be null?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `ManyToOne(optional = true)` for Dealer and User

Comment: you can also consider using ManyToAny mapping [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-column-any)

Comment: Maybe this blog can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718229/can-a-manytoone-jpa-relation-be-null