# How to map optional ID field to entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, mapstruct

I have entity called Franchise and this entity looks like this:

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "franchises")
public class Franchise {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private FranchiseType type;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_id")
    private Country country;
}
```

I have following api endpoint for creating new Franchise entity: `POST /api/franchise`
And fields that I need to send are: `name`, `type` and `countryId`. `countryId` is optional field and can be null in the database (column `country_id`).

I am using mapstruct to map `CreateFranchiseDTO` to `Franchise`:

```java
@Data
public class CreateFranchiseDTO {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Long countryId;
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface FranchiseDTOMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "countryId", target = "country.id")
    Franchise fromCreateFranchiseDTO(CreateFranchiseDTO dto);
}
```

When I call above mentioned api endpoint with `countryId` set to some integer (which exists in `countries` table) everythng works. But if I call endpoint without `countryId` field in request body and when the following code executes I get exception `object references an unsaved transient instance`:

```java
Franchise franchise = franchiseDTOMapper.fromCreateFranchiseDTO(dto);
franchiseRepository.save(franchise);
```

When I look at the debugger I can see that `franchise.getCountry()` is equal to `Country` object with all fields set to NULL or zero/false (default values for primitives)

I have few options to solve this:

1. using `@AfterMapping` and check for `franchise.getCountry().getId() == null`
2. create following method in mapper: `Country longToCountry(Long id)`

But it seems to me that I am missing something or I am wrong. So how do I map an optional ID (relation) to field using mapstruct?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have the same problem as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718229/can-a-manytoone-jpa-relation-be-null).

What seems to have worked for that person was to use `optional = true`:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Comment: `optional = true` is default value

Comment: Ah, you're right. Seems I didn't do my research properly before answering.

For anyone curious, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) is some documentation